# Create a 3-Qubit circuit given the state?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

I am trying to implement a 3-qubit circuit given the state. I have been given for example : |w> = x*|010> + y*<101>. How can I reverse engineer to create the desired state. As I am confused about the approach towards the process. I tried initial dab, but this was more of trial and error rather than calculated approach. I would appreciate some resources or derivation.

```
        q = QuantumRegister(3)
        c = ClassicalRegister(2)
        qcirc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)

        # Put the first qubit into a superposition
        qcirc.h(q[0])

        # Apply the first controlled-not gate
        qcirc.cx(q[0], q[1])

        # Apply the rotation gate to the second qubit
        angle = np.arccos(np.sqrt(3)/4)
        qcirc.p(angle, q[1])

        # Apply the second controlled-not gate
        qcirc.cx(q[0], q[2])

        # Apply the rotation gate to the third qubit
        angle = np.arccos(1/2)
        qcirc.p(angle, q[2])
```

Comment: What do you mean by reverse engineer? Do you just want to construct circuit preparing the state?

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Are trying to prepare circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to create the one-qubit state $\cos(\theta)|0\rangle + \sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}|1\rangle$. This can be done by doing, for example, the sequence of $R_x(\gamma)R_z(\beta)R_x(\alpha)$. This is not difficult to figure out numerically, so I will let you do this part.

Now, to solve your problem, first rotate a one-qubit state in this way to your desired coefficients. Then append two more qubits to it, so you have
$\cos(\theta)|000\rangle + \sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}|100\rangle$.

Now, your desired state can be created by the operating $X_1CX_{02}CX_{01}$ on this state, yielding $\cos(\theta)|010\rangle + \sin(\theta)e^{i\phi}|101\rangle$.